# Missing required 'subjectId' parameter for Sending a Direct Message Connect REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, connect-api, direct-messaging

[Send a Direct Message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_element_direct_message.htm?q=/chatter/feed-elements%20direct)

URL above is giving me the endpoint and body for sending a direct message in community. When run in workbench, the DirectMessage, DirectMessageFeed, and FeedItem record was created.

But when it is run in apex, it is having a **"Missing required 'subjectId' parameter."** error. I'm having the same body in both workbench and apex class.

Below is my code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String saveMessage(String subject, String message, String communityId, Id recipientId, Id senderId){
    Lightning_Communities_Settings__c setting = Lightning_Communities_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();
    String baseUrl = setting.Connect_API_BASE_URL__c;
    String endpoint = baseUrl + communityId + '/chatter/feed-elements';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:Salesforce_Instance' + endpoint);
    req.setTimeout(StringConstants_HTTP.TIMEDOUT_120000);
    req.setHeader(StringConstants_HTTP.HEADER_FIELD_AUTH, StringConstants_HTTP.HEADER_FIELD_BEARER + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    
    //String jsonPayload = '{"body":{"messageSegments":[{"type":"Text","text":"' + message + '"}]},"capabilities":{"directMessage":{"membersToAdd":["' + recipientId + '", "' + senderId + '":],"subjectId":"' + subject + '"}},"feedElementType":"FeedItem"}';
    String jsonPayload = '{"body":{"messageSegments":[{"type":"Text","text":"Thanks for attending my presentation test run this morning. Send me any feedback."}]},"capabilities":{"directMessage":{"membersToAdd":["005050000031T0E","00505000002fvScAAI"],"subject":"Thank you!"}},"feedElementType":"FeedItem"}';

    req.setBody(jsonPayload);
    req.setMethod(StringConstants_HTTP.REQUEST_METHOD_POST);

    try {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug('Response Body : '+res.getBody());
        return res.getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

If I put the subjectId in the payload, in workbench, I'm having an error of
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: 1) The [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_requests_feed_item_input.htm#connect_requests_feed_item_input) says `subjectId` is required so maybe you need `"subjectId" : null`;